# Why mysql JDBC driver returns TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED as default isolation level

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

As I know default transaction isolation level for Mysql DB is REPEATABLE_READ. (see [Mysql Transaction Isolation Levels](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/innodb-transaction-isolation-levels.html)). But Mysql connector 8 has following code:

```
public class DatabaseMetaData implements java.sql.DatabaseMetaData {
...
    @Override  
    public int getDefaultTransactionIsolation() throws SQLException {
        return java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED;
    }
}
```

They just ignore default `REPEATABLE_READ` and set less restricted `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`.

It is not clear for me why they did it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The default for the MySQL Connector/J JDBC driver is not `TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ`, it is `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` as communicated by that `DatabaseMetaData` implementation. So, although MySQL itself may default to repeatable read when no transaction configuration is specified, the JDBC driver will use read committed as its default when creating transactions.

The choice for `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED` is likely historical, the previous default engine of MySQL was MyISAM, and this engine does not actually support transactions, so any change was technically immediately committed, and therefor any read would read those new rows. For MyISAM the behaviour matches - largely - `TRANSACTION_READ_COMMITTED`.

However, we cannot answer with certainty why the developers of MySQL Connector/J really chose this as the default. The JDBC specification itself does not require a specific default, but in my experience, a lot of JDBC drivers use this as the default.

Comment: This is further confused by the fact that calling `DriverManager.getConnection()` will return a `Connection` whose transaction-isolation level may not be set to the driver's default. For example, if you connect to an InnoDB database, the "default" becomes `REPEATABLE_READ`. That is, the db metadata will return one value while a freshly-established `Connection` may return something else.

Answer (score 2):

Actually, in `mysql-connector-j:8.0.31`, the default is indeed TRANSACTION_REPEATABLE_READ:

[image]

So it really depends on the version of the driver you're using.